# Vectors how and when do I multiply a negative in a bracket

Tags: vectors

I'm currently revising Vectors and am a little stuck. I am watching through a MathsWatch clip and got stuck when multiplying a negative in a bracket.  AS you can see at the end of question B they ended up with: 1/3y + 2/3x, however I ended up with 2/3x-1/3y when following AC to CT. What did I do wrong?

[image: Image from mathswatch]

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the value $\frac{2}{3}$ with each term within the brackets, namely $x$ and $-y$ (notice you have to keep the negative sign). You should get

$$y + \frac{2}{3}(x-y) = y + \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{2}{3}y$$

Group together the y:s to get $\frac{1}{3}y + \frac{2}{3}x$.

Comment: But when I done it I had x outside of the brackets

Comment: Please show us how you did it then.

Comment: How do I add the mathematical symbols like you did above

Comment: @HarryKitchener Using LaTeX and putting it between dollar signs \$...\$.